# Android Virtual Device Ok button not clickable

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've been following an android development book thoroughly, i am told to create a virtual device manager on eclipse. With steps being followed, i can't seem to click the ok button, it's not clickable. Any idea why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show what you have done?

Comment: What "OK button" are you talking about?